# Distribution Profile error: Valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning, adhoc

When I create a Development Provisioning Profile (to distribute the app Ad-Hoc) the organizer in Xcode gives the following error: Valid signing identity not found.

I tried the steps below to solve my problem without any luck:

- remove all keys and certificates in my Keychain.
- revoked my Development Certificate in the iOS Provisioning Portal
- created a new Development Certificate
- edited the Development Provisioning Profile for my app and selected my Certificate.
- Xcode says my profile is valid for de Development Provisiong Profile.
- created the Distribution Provisioning Profile.
- Xcode says there is no valid signing identity found for the Distribution Provisiong Profile.

What other solutions can I try? There is already an app in the App Store publish by my colleague.

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1

Answer (score 2):

This happen when you miss the private key of the certificate signer. You must have the private key in your keychain.

Usually when you request certificate from a certificate authority, it created a private key in your keychain, which subsequently used for creating all the provisioning profiles.

Comment: This was the correct answer for my case. Especially if you are administering multiple build machines, this step can be easily missed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing one important step. 'Request a certificate from certificate authority'.
Please have a look at [this](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/506-Creating-your-iOS-Certificates).

Comment: I did that in step 3 (created a new Development Certificate). There is already a Distribution Certificate present in the Provisioning Portal (created by my colleague).

Comment: @JoshuaLückers: what about the bundle id? are you using the correct one?

Comment: @Anjaly The App ID for the certificate you mean? That one is correct.